# Table view disappears in custom animation

Tags: swift, uitableview, animation, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I wrote the following function to implement custom animation:

```
func AnimateIt()
{
    println("here")

    var mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    var aNavigationController2 = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TNavigationController") as! UINavigationController

    var aInfo = aNavigationController2.viewControllers[0] as! AInfoVC

    self.view.addSubview(aInfo.view)
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(aInfo.view)

    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = false

    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, animations: {

        aInfo.view.frame.origin.x += self.view.frame.width

        }) { (finished) -> Void in

            aInfo.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

The '**AInfoVC**' has a table view, which disappears when the above animation starts.  Similar functions work properly for the other view controller which has not table view.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't find you question.

Comment: dasdom, during animation table view, which is a part of the 'AInfoVC' view controller disappears